# How to install nemo extensions?

Tags: software-installation, nemo

I have ubuntu 16.04 and Nemo file manager. I downloaded nemo file extensions from here:

https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions

First, where are details of the extensions?

Second, how do I 'install' this extension from zip file in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install the extensions from the zip file by opening up the zip file and compiling and building the extension that you want to install.

As an Ubuntu-user, you likely need to manually install [mint-dev-tools](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_main/ulyana/main/base/mint-dev-tools) before building the project, if it can't find the `mint-build`-command.

You can build the extension by running from a terminal prompt:

```
$ ./build [extension name]
```

Replace extension name with the name of the extension you want to build.  For example you could build the nemo-terminal extension with:

```
$ ./build nemo-terminal
```

When the build is completed, install the generated `nemo-terminal-VERSIONNAME.deb` (make sure the file is allowed to execute as a program).

During the compiling and build process you may get errors indicating that you need certain development packages.  You can install a dependence package using `apt-get`.  For instance once of the packages used for some of the extensions is `libglib2.0-dev`.  If you don't have it installed you'd have to install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Most of the `github` downloads will have instructions of how to build the packages included in the zip or the git-hub directory branch.

There may be occasions where you might have to read some of the comments on the site to resolve some of the issues the users are having when compiling and building some of the individual packages.

Comment: Works! Don't forget to follow up with `sudo dpkg -i [package name].deb`. You need to build and install `python-nemo` before you can install `nemo-terminal`.

Comment: is there a way to do that with an rpm based distribution?

Comment: Is it possible to install nemo-terminal using Ubuntu instead of Linux Mint?