# Can't install nemo-seahorse

Tags: filemanager, cinnamon, nemo, seahorse

I've tried installing nemo-seahorse extension for nemo file manager after installing it as given in the following sites

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html
http://www.noobslab.com/2017/01/latest-nemo-file-manager-with.html

but every time I tried to install nemo-seahorse using the command `sudo apt-get install nemo-seahorse` I would get an error something like:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nemo-seahorse_3.2.0-1~webupd8~xenial0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/seahorse-tool', which is also in package seahorse-nautilus 3.11.92-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nemo-seahorse_3.2.0-1~webupd8~xenial0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

or

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nemo-seahorse_3.2.0-b~xenial~NoobsLab.com_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/seahorse-tool', which is also in package seahorse-nautilus 3.11.92-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nemo-seahorse_3.2.0-b~xenial~NoobsLab.com_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I've removed the packages and PPA each time and now installed the nemo using sudo apt-get install nemo the default one available in ubuntu and tried to build the extensions as given in this site: 
[How to install nemo extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827659/how-to-install-nemo-extensions) 
But it's still not working I got this in the terminal at the end:

```
gpg: skipped "Clement Lefebvre <root@linuxmint.com>": No secret key
gpg: dpkg-sign.2qaQaPF8/nemo-seahorse_3.2.0.dsc: clearsign failed: No secret key

dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .dsc and .changes file
```

so the extension is not installed? How can I install it? And in the list of extensions in the nemo file manager, I can only find nemo-fileroller selected and can't see anymore extensions. But I think I'll not get updates for the extension if I install through building. Sorry if I'm doing some very basic mistake and thank you for taking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you do *not* use nautilus file manager**

If you use nautilus at all, stop here, and jump to the next section.

It looks like in your first attempt, the ppa was trying to overwrite a nautilus or nautilus plugin dependency on your system. Overwriting would be bad because it could break nautilus, so the system stops you. If you don't use nautilus, you could try removing it entirely:

- `sudo apt-get remove nautilus seahorse-nautilus`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` # gets rid of nautilus extras hanging around
- Try installing from ppa again `sudo apt-get install nemo-seahorse`

---

**If you *do* use nautilus**

You may be able to complete the install from ppa if you simply get rid of the `seahorse-nautilus` package followed by the autoremove command.

- `sudo apt-get remove seahorse-nautilus`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` # gets rid of extra unused dependencies hanging around
- Try installing from ppa again `sudo apt-get install nemo-seahorse`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and tell you :), sorry for the late reply, I've been busy

Comment: I've a doubt though, if I remove seahorse-nautilus, then I won't be able to encrypt using nautilus file manager right? Is there a way to make both of them work? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it looks like it got installed properly, but the no file is getting created when I press on encrypt after right click, seahorse is opening, and I'm able to choose the key, but when I press ok, no new encrypted file is getting created. Sorry for asking this here, but do you have any idea?

Comment: I've not used nemo-seahorse to be honest. You'd probably be able to learn more by posting a new question with screenshots and a description of the steps you're taking. There may be someone else who is better able to answer that question than I could.

Comment: The challenge in getting both seahorse-nautilus and nemo-nautilus to work lies in the fact that they apparently (from the errors you're seeing above) share some dependencies. This means that both seahorse-nautilus and nemo-nautilus must be capable of using the *same* version of those dependencies. If they are both trying to use different versions of the same dependency, you will run into the problem you see above where one program is not allowed to install its version of the dependency over the other program's dependency version. If they're not both in the same repo, there's no simple fix.