# Is it possible to install nemo-compare on ubuntu 18.04? if so, how?

Tags: nemo, extension

I found this:
https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/

but here is not mint, is ubuntu 18.04

This extension code is in python.

It is the only reason that I still open nautilus for: to compare files easily...

this didnt work for me: [How to install nemo extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827659/how-to-install-nemo-extensions)
I tried to download and `./build nemo-compare` on ubuntu 18.04, but it requires nemo-3.8 and here is 3.6, found no updates to it.

there are some other files for older ubuntu, but I see no reason to them not work on 18.04, they are at:
https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3/+packages
I just dont know what to do with them...
If extensions could be installed for my user only and not at `/usr` it would be easier, but I found no info where it should be placed.

I tried temporarily copy them to `/usr/share/nemo-compare` and create a symlink for the main file at `/usr/share/nemo-python/extensions/` but when restarting nemo, it didnt detect the extension... (so I removed all these tmp changes)

Comment: for 20.04 there is a workaround: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/issues/375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have two possible solutions:

- clone the git-repository, patch code and create deb-package locally:

  ```
  # get development stuff
  sudo apt-get install git devscripts debhelper python-all dh-python

  # clone repository
  cd ~/Downloads
  git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions.git
  cd nemo-extensions/nemo-compare
  git checkout 3.6.0

  # patch (Ubuntu has 'nemo-python' instead of 'python-nemo')
  sed -i "s/python-nemo/nemo-python/" debian/control

  # build deb-package and install it
  debuild -uc -us
  sudo apt-get install ../nemo-compare_3.6.0_all.deb
  ```

  and then restart Nemo.
- find [some PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) on the LaunchPad with precompiled Nemo Extensions [packages](https://launchpad.net/~gfunkmonk/+archive/ubuntu/nemo):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gfunkmonk/nemo
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nemo-compare
  ```

  and then restart Nemo.

Comment: thx!!! just that for some reason I had to `sudo apt-get install python-nemo nemo-compare` instead, while using the ppa :>

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu 20.04 (a mix of previous answers):

- download https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/archive/4.0.0.tar.gz
- extract archive
- build nemo-compare:

  ```
   cd nemo-extensions-4.0.0
   cd nemo-compare
   sed -i "s/python-nemo/nemo-python/" debian/control
   cd ..
   sudo ./build nemo-compare
   sudo apt-get install ./nemo-compare_4.0.0_all.deb
  ```
- restart nemo

Comment: you can use the latest too, currently 4.6.0 from https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/ by downloading the master branch. There is also the alternative to accept both package names https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/issues/375#issuecomment-691768340

Comment: At step 4:
`./build: line 18: mint-build: command not found`
What should I do?

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu 22.04 but didn't work. End up by using nautilus as in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417245/nautilus-compare-on-22-04